# I keep getting this error " import error: 'useNavigate' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'."

Tags: reactjs

I have imported the useNavigate but I am still getting error stating that it is not exported from react router dom

```
import {useState} from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Login({setUser}) {

    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const [loginData, setLoginData] = useState({
        username: '',
        password: ''
    })
```

Comment: please give more information about your environment and make a minimal reproduce it better.@Ri H

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your using react-router-dom 6.2.x and also the main routes should be like this in parent component.
[image]